# Can avocado plant get direct March sunlight in a mediterranean area?

Tags: avocado, sunlight

I've been learning a lot about avocadoes in the past months. Specially about indoor avocado plants.  My avocados have always been next to a window without getting direct light (more like the reflection of the direct light on the building in front).

Now starting mid March and until September or so, I will be getting more and more direct sunlight in one room. Should I move my avocado plants to this room? Is it okay for the avocado plants (the oldest one is 4-5 months old) to suddenly get direct sunlight if they have never gotten?

I've read about a period of transition, but I guess that the sunlight's intensity is not the same now in March than in June

Environment info:
Outside avg temperature is 15 degrees Celsius. Indoors with the direct sunlight (thermometer), 33 Celsius. Mediterranean country. Area: more or less dry environment.

[image]